# What gesture can execute code only while user placing their finger on the screen in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, uigesturerecognizer

What gesture can execute code only while user placing their finger on the screen?

Running certain code should not be Effect of the Cause(gesture), what I want is running certain code while user holding their finger on the screen, and if the user took their finger off the code stops running

For example,

```
//some view
.unknownGesture{
// running this code only while user placing their finger on the screen
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible solution

```
.gesture(
  DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
    .onChanged() { event in
      print(">>> activated")
    })
```